# How to make background element not clickable on ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

On my website I have something like this:

```
<div id="videoContainer">
<section id="dynamicContent">lorem ipsum...</section>
<video id="video">
...
</video>
</div>
```

Now `#dynamicContent` and `#video` positions are absolute (both 100% width and height). I want `#dynamicContent` to overlay the video. Now everything works just fine on desktop browsers. The problem is that when I enter the website using iPad and click on the overlaying block (`#dynamicContent`) the device is trying to click on everything under this overlaying block. For example: when I click on the middle of the `#dynamicContent,` the video starts even if it's under the block. When I do the same for example in PC Firefox, nothing happens and this is what I'm trying to accomplish. How can I do this?

Some fiddle: [attempts](http://jsfiddle.net/wmd5Y/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your `<section>` is a sibling of your `<video>` and as it is the first child of your `#videoContainer` it is not on top of `<video>` but below.

Is there any js involved?

Comment: I've changed their places... didn't help. No JS involved. http://jsfiddle.net/wmd5Y/7/